# Can I integrate a navigation graph inside a fragment in my app with multiple fragments and a tab layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller

I am making an app which has 3 fragments tablayout. And in one of the fragments, I want to add navigation-graph. Is it possible to achieve this?